# How would i create a dictionary from a CSV file without using any modules or importing CSV?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

When I'm given a CSV file containing:

```
file1 = '"Name","Weight","Height","EyeColor"

"Jimmy","145","160","Blue"

"Kim","120","150","Brown"

"Sean","170","188","Red"'
```

My answer should return:

```
{'Jimmy': [(145,160,'Blue')], 'Kim': [(120,150,'Brown')], 'Sean': [(170,188,'Red')]}
```

[image]

There's my current code, i'd truly appreciate the help.

Comment: If it helps, the weight and height have to be integers and the eye color a string

Comment: Thanks, but say the Names weren't already in alphabetical order. How would i be able to execute that?

Comment: Why do you need a single tuple wrapped in a single-element list?

Comment: If there were say more than one value equal to a single key, so a list of tuples equaled to a single key

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any modules, you could just split the file based on it's delimiter - in this case, `,`.  In so doing, you'd be left with a list of the data, with each individual attribute being an element in the list.

To get the `dict` the way you want it, we then use a `list` slice to divvy up the elements:

```
csv_dict = {}
for line in open('your_csv_file.csv', 'r').readlines()[1:]:
    line = line.replace('\n', '')
    line = line.split(',')
    csv_dict[line[0]] = line[1:]
```

This will leave you with a `dict` with the names as keys and the other attributes as those keys values in a list.

Comment: The code `csv_dict[line[0]]: line[1:]` does not works

Comment: The output is like this `{'"Name"': ['"Weight"', '"Height"', '"EyeColor"\n'], '"Kim"': ['"120"', '"150"', '"Brown"\n'], '"Jimmy"': ['"145"', '"160"', '"Blue"\n'], '"Sean"': ['"170"', '"188"', '"Red"\'\n']}' which is slight different from the answer...but I got the idea..

Comment: Edited version should fix that up.

Comment: To get integer weight and height `csv_dict[line[0]] = (int(line[1], int(line[2], line[3])`

Answer (score 0):

I changed your function a little bit. The code follows bellow:

```
def readf(somefile):
    my_dict = {}
    with open(somefile, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines()[1:]:
            line = line.rstrip()
            line = line.replace('"', '')
            items = line.split(',')
            my_dict[items[0]] = [int(items[1]), int(items[2]), items[3]]
    return my_dict

# print keys in alphabetical order
my_list = list(my_dict.keys())
my_list.sort()
print(my_list)
```

Comment: Thanks, say the names werent already in alphabetical order. How would be able arrange them by values because I know you can't sort keys but you can values?

Comment: You can put the keys in a list and sort it. AFAIK you can't sort the keys in a dictionary. Se http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key for more info.

Comment: You can save your data in a pandas Dataframe, that way, you can define the names as keys and sort them.

Comment: What if there was another guy named Jimmy and he had different characteristics but i wanted to put both tuples under the name Jimmy. Does the code already take care of that because of the my_dict[item[0]]=[item1...]?

Comment: Your code would replace the old Jimmy for the new Jimmy. One thing that you could do is to check if items[0] already exists as a key in my_dict using if my_dict.has_key(items[0]): If the answer is true you could append the new value with the old value, creating a list with two persons.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [21]: def readf(somefile):
...:     my_dict = {}
...:     with open(somefile, 'r') as f:
...:         for i, line in enumerate(f):
...:             if i == 0:
...:                 continue
...:             line = line.replace('\"', '')
...:             line = line.replace('\n', '')
...:             items = line.split(',')
...:             key, values = items[0], [(int(items[1]), int(items[2])], items[3])
...:             my_dict[key] = values
...:     return my_dict
...:

In [22]: d = readf('file1')

In [23]: d
Out[23]:
{'Jimmy': [(145, 160, 'Blue')],
 'Kim': [(120, 150, 'Brown')],
 'Sean': [(170, 188, 'Red')]}
```